# Conflict using List/ScrollView with SFSafariViewController fullscreen sheet

Tags: swiftui, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am trying to make a list of items each item should open a sheet with SFSafariViewController in full screen. To show SFSafariViewController in full screen, I used the code available in this link: https://dev.to/uchcode/web-sheet-with-sfsafariviewcontroller-4nlc. The controller working very fine. However, when I put the items inside a List or ScrollView, it does not show the sheet. When I remove List/ScrollView it works fine.

Here is the code.

```
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct RootView: View, Hostable {
    @EnvironmentObject private var hostedObject: HostingObject<Self>
    let address: String
    let title: String
    
    func present() {
        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
        config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
        
        let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: address)!, configuration: config)
        hostedObject.viewController?.present(safari, animated: true)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(title) {
            self.present()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var articlesList = [
    ArticlesList(id: 0, title: "Apple", link: "http://apple.com", lang: "en"),
    ArticlesList(id: 1, title: "Yahoo", link: "http://yahoo.com", lang: "en"),
    ArticlesList(id: 2, title: "microsoft", link: "http://microsoft.com", lang: "en"),
    ArticlesList(id: 3, title: "Google", link: "http://google.com", lang: "en")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            //Here is the problem when I add RootView inside a List or ScrollView it does not show Safari.
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack{
                    ForEach(articlesList) {article in
                        RootView(address: article.link, title: article.title).hosting()
                        Spacer(minLength: 10)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Articles")
        }
    }
    
}

struct ArticlesList: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let link: String
    let lang: String
}


struct UIViewControllerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    final class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var didAppear: (UIViewController) -> Void = { _ in }
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            didAppear(self)
        }
    }
    
    var didAppear: (UIViewController) -> Void
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.didAppear = didAppear
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        //
    }
}

struct UIViewControllerViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    var didAppear: (UIViewController) -> Void
    var viewControllerView: some View {
        UIViewControllerView(didAppear:didAppear).frame(width:0,height:0)
    }
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(viewControllerView)
    }
}

extension View {
    func uiViewController(didAppear: @escaping (UIViewController) -> ()) -> some View {
        modifier(UIViewControllerViewModifier(didAppear:didAppear))
    }
}

class HostingObject<Content: View>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewController: UIViewController? = nil
}

struct HostingObjectView<Content: View>: View {
    var rootView: Content
    let hostedObject = HostingObject<Content>()
    func getHost(viewController: UIViewController) {
        hostedObject.viewController = viewController.parent
    }
    var body: some View {
        rootView
            .uiViewController(didAppear: getHost(viewController:))
            .environmentObject(hostedObject)
    }
}

protocol Hostable: View {
    associatedtype Content: View
    func hosting() -> Content
}

extension Hostable {
    func hosting() -> some View {
        HostingObjectView(rootView: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to get more/better answers if you post compiling code. For example, remove the `getArticles` function and the `LoadingView`, add some test data, and make sure everything can be copy/pasted into a new SwiftUI project which then immediately compiles.

Comment: @BartvanKuik , I edited the question to have one code ready for new SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the working code..

```
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View{
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
            }.tag(0)
            
            ArticlesView().hosting()
                .tabItem{
                    VStack{
                        Image(systemName: "quote.bubble")
                        Text("Articles")
                    }
            }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View{
        Text("This is home")
    }
}


struct ShareView: View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("Here the share")
    }
}

struct ArticlesView: View, Hostable {
    @EnvironmentObject private var hostedObject: HostingObject<Self>
    @State private var showShare = false
    
    @State private var articlesList = [
        ArticlesList(id: 0, title: "Apple", link: "http://apple.com", lang: "en"),
        ArticlesList(id: 1, title: "Yahoo", link: "http://yahoo.com", lang: "en"),
        ArticlesList(id: 2, title: "microsoft", link: "http://microsoft.com", lang: "en"),
        ArticlesList(id: 3, title: "Google", link: "http://google.com", lang: "en")
    ]
    
    
    func present(address: String) {
        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
        config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
        
        let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: address)!, configuration: config)
        hostedObject.viewController?.present(safari, animated: true)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 40){
                    ForEach(articlesList) {article in
                        Button(article.title) {
                            self.present(address: article.link)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showShare){
                    ShareView()
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Articles")
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showShare.toggle()
                    })
                    {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ArticlesList: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let link: String
    let lang: String
}



struct UIViewControllerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    final class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var didAppear: (UIViewController) -> Void = { _ in }
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            didAppear(self)
        }
    }
    
    var didAppear: (UIViewController) -> Void
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.didAppear = didAppear
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        //
    }
}

struct UIViewControllerViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    var didAppear: (UIViewController) -> Void
    var viewControllerView: some View {
        UIViewControllerView(didAppear:didAppear).frame(width:0,height:0)
    }
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(viewControllerView)
    }
}

extension View {
    func uiViewController(didAppear: @escaping (UIViewController) -> ()) -> some View {
        modifier(UIViewControllerViewModifier(didAppear:didAppear))
    }
}

class HostingObject<Content: View>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewController: UIViewController? = nil
}

struct HostingObjectView<Content: View>: View {
    var rootView: Content
    let hostedObject = HostingObject<Content>()
    func getHost(viewController: UIViewController) {
        hostedObject.viewController = viewController.parent
    }
    var body: some View {
        rootView
            .uiViewController(didAppear: getHost(viewController:))
            .environmentObject(hostedObject)
    }
}

protocol Hostable: View {
    associatedtype Content: View
    func hosting() -> Content
}

extension Hostable {
    func hosting() -> some View {
        HostingObjectView(rootView: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in the iOS 14 simulator!

I wrapped SFSafariViewController, and if I replace your `RootView` with the following code, it works on my iOS 13 device. However it's not really full-screen but it's a sheet.

```
struct RootView: View {
    @State private var isPresenting = false
    let address: String
    let title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(self.title) {
            self.isPresenting.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresenting) {
            SafariView(address: URL(string: self.address)!)
        }
    }
}

struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let address: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SFSafariViewController {
        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
        config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true

        let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: self.address, configuration: config)
        return safari
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: Context) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works in iOS 14, does it mean it is a bug in previous versions like 13.7? I am not sure if the sheet would be OK for the user. I will make a test.

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. Right now, I don't have a device available that runs the iOS 14 beta. But I'd surely want to test it there, before drawing the conclusion that it's an iOS 13 bug, and it really works on iOS 14.

Comment: @BartvanKuik Hey! Were you able to find a fix?

Comment: @KennyBatista I hope the answer below is found helpful.